# Warnings using format strings with sprintf() in C++

Tags: c++, types, format, printf

Compiling this lines

```
    long int sz;
    char tmpret[128];

    //take substring of c, translate in c string, convert to int, 
    //and multiply with 1024
    sz=atoi(c.substr(0,pos).c_str())*1024;

    snprintf(tmpret,128,"%l",sz);
```

I read two warning on snprintf line:

```
 warning: conversion lacks type at end of format
 warning: too many arguments for format
```

Why? The type is specified (long int sz, and %l in snprintf) and the argument in snprintf is only one. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your format lacks type, because l is a "sizeof" modifier. Should be %ld

Answer (score 1):

`boost::lexical_cast<string>(sz)` is much nicer, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

See this list of [printf format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf.html)

It's comment for %l is:

> The argument is interpreted as a long
>   int or unsigned long int for integer
>   specifiers (i, d, o, u, x and X), and
>   as a wide character or wide character
>   string for specifiers c and s.

Answer (score -1):

int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );

It does not require the length of "str", as the second argument.
 The name of the string pointer/ array name is enough.

Comment: sprintf() is quite unsafe, as it is not bounds checked.  You are better off using an alternative, if available, to avoid buffer overruns.